# The $2$-norm of a Hermitian matrix does not exceed its $1$-norm

Tags: matrices, inequality, normed-spaces

How to prove that the $2$-norm of a Hermitian matrix does not exceed its $1$-norm?

In wiki, I see $2$-norm of matrix $A$ is $\le \sqrt{\|A\|_1\|A\|_\infty}$. But I don't know how to prove that either. Can anyone help on that?

Comment: $\|A\|_2^2=\rho(A^*A)\leq\|A^*A\|_\infty\leq\|A^*\|_\infty\|A\|_\infty=\|A\|_1\|A\|_\infty$

Comment: What did you really want to prove:  the statement in the title or the statement in the body of the post?